# Why can't Jenkins build script change to a directory?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to build a jenkins job with below lines of code and it is failing.

```
cd ../../../../../
cd /home/skasturi/sdk/
cp -pr 8.0_Sprint2 8.0_Sprint3
```

Console output of jenkins build:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SMGR_SDK
[SMGR_SDK] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3461562069624051922.sh
+ cd ../../../../../
+ cd /home/skasturi/sdk/
/tmp/jenkins3461562069624051922.sh: line 3: cd: /home/skasturi/sdk/: Not a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

What might be the cause of the observer behavior?

Comment: Try to provide your problem more clearer.Also paste the console log clearly.

Comment: Do you Directory -- Mentioned /home/skasturi/sdk.. check once and check the permissions it have.

Comment: if Possible paste the Console image you got and how you have configured steps also as image.

Comment: Permissions of /home/skasturi/sdk is as below.
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root     root         4096 Aug  3 12:23 sdk

Comment: How you configured the steps to run the process can you explain.

Comment: Steps as below:
1. Created a "Freestyle project"
2. And in "Build" section,i have added one "Execute shell" step.

Comment: Steps as below:
1. Created a "Freestyle project"
2. And in "Build" section,i have added one "Execute shell" step.
3 . In "Execute Shell" step, i have added below lines.
     cd ../../../../../
     cd /home/skasturi/sdk/
     cp -pr 8.0_Sprint2 8.0_Sprint3

Comment: Your final goal is ->go to that directory sdk and what do you want next to be done..??

Comment: I will be executing the below lines if the above copy commnad is sucessful.

1 . sed -i 's/7.1.2.0-SNAPSHOT/8.0.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT/g' 
     sdkdownload_pom.xml
2. mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=$g_id -DartifactId=$a_id -Dversion=8.0.0.0.2-26794-SDK-1.0 -Durl=https://zzz.com/repository/smgr-maven2-release -DrepositoryId=smgr-maven2-release -Dsmgr_automationlogin=smgr-automation -Dsmgr_automationpassword=xxxxxx -s settings_nexus3.xml -Dfile=target/$a_name -Dpackaging=$a_type -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: Is sdk is folder or file??

Comment: Have check the copy process manually in your system like this before??

Comment: you can remove the first line of your script: `cd ../../../../../`. that isn't necessary if you are going to subsequently `cd` to an absolute directory. instead of `cd /home/skasturi/sdk/`, can you `ls -l /home/skasturi` and `stat /home/skasturi/sdk` and paste the results?

Comment: The issue is with jenkins service.My jenkins is running as "jenkins" user and hence it is not working.I have started the jenkins service as "root" user and after that the jenkins build is sucessful.

Now can someone tell me how can i always run the jenkins service as a "root" user?

Comment: Got the answer...i have changed /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and added JENKINS_USER="root".Now jenkins service is running under roor user.